# Extracting variable values from link string

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have in table column saved web page links in this kind of format:

> https://website.com/?variable1=aaa&variable2=222&variable3=ccc&variable4=dd44

There might be different page names, different parameter count etc.

My target is to get value of "variable2" which is "222". We can assume that "variable2" is always present in link.

So far I have came across this kind of solution, which works correctly, but doesn't look efficient enough:

```
select
    substring(t.link, position('variable2=' in t.link)+10,
                position('&' in substring(t.link, position('variable2=' in t.link)+10))-1)
from
    (select
    'https://website.com/?variable1=aaa&variable2=222&variable3=ccc&variable4=dd44' as link
    )t;
```

I believe this could be done with a single substring function:

```
substring(string from pattern for escape)
```

So far I managed to get substring until last appearance of "&" with these two different approaches:

```
substring(t.link from '%variable2=#"%#"&%' for '#'),
substring(t.link from 'variable2=(.+)&')
```

both of them give same result: "222&variable3=ccc"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `substring(link from 'variable2=[^&]+')` seems to do the job

Comment: Not exatly. I get value "variable2=222", but i would like to retrieve just "222".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution using regex lookbehind:

```
select (regexp_matches(link,'(?<=variable2=)[^&]*'))[1]
FROM mytable
```

`(?<=variable=)` matches strings that are preceded by `variable=`

`[^&]*` matches all strings up to the first `&`

`regexp_matches` returns an array, and we want the first (*only*) match.

the array-index `[1]` picks the first match.

**Update:**

Since we are interested in the first match, the following statement also works:

```
select substring(link from '(?<=variable2=)[^&]*')
from mytable
```

Comment: Finaly! Actually no need to use regexp_matches, I just used substring with same pattern: substring(t.link from '(?<=variable2=)[^&]*') 
Work like a charm!

Comment: nice! i didn't know substring can do that. will update answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring to extract the key/value pair, then use `split_part()` to extract the delimited value:

```
split_part(substring(link from 'variable2=[^&]+'), '=', 2);
```

Comment: This looks much more elegant than my current solution. But can't it be achieved with just single substring function? My solutions get correct start of substring, your solution get correct end of substring. Can't both solutions somehow combined? Jus curious, I know, I am not an expert in pattern matching.